# How to enable/disable (show/hide) child widgets in a stateless widget (screen)

Tags: flutter, statelesswidget

My app has a screen that is composed of several buttons and text labels which are conditionally visible based on the selection of the buttons (for example, a yes/no radio button asking whether you were exposed to a covid-positive individual, which would cause another radio button asking whether  the encounter lasted more than 15 minutes to be displayed).

1. I know that stateless widgets for screens are preferable due to their improved performance, so I am trying to keep the screen widget stateless
2. The radio buttons in the example are actually custom statefull widgets wrapping a [ToggleButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html), so I would have the condition (controlling the visibility of widget) to *flow* between the main stateless widget and the statefull child widgets (with the toggle buttons)

Comment: You can use packages like Provider & GetX

Comment: thanks. I was't aware of GetX. It seems great. definitely adopting it.
I would appreciate a short code snippet that demonstrates enabling and hiding a button in a stateless widget based on a state of another child widget